# how to configure single propery place holder for entire project

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

In my project, I have multiple context files.In that I am loading the property files using the property place holder like below.

Below are my context.xml files.

```
a.xml
       <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/devconfiguration.xml" />
        <!--<property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/sitconfiguration.xml" />
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/uatconfiguration.xml" />
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/prodconfiguration.xml" />-->
        </bean>

b.xml
       <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/devconfiguration.xml" />
        <!--<property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/sitconfiguration.xml" />
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/uatconfiguration.xml" />
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/prodconfiguration.xml" />-->
        </bean>

c.xml
       <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/devconfiguration.xml" />
        <!--<property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/sitconfiguration.xml" />
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/uatconfiguration.xml" />
            <property name="location" value="file:${conf.path}/prodconfiguration.xml" />-->
        </bean>
```

While taking war file each time we are going to change all context files. Is their any way to have one property place holder for entire project.
I tried but I am not able to load property files without using property place holder bean. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely depends on the build tool - [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can import definitions of `b.xml` and `c.xml` into `a.xml`

```
<beans> // a.xml
...
    <import resource="classpath:b.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:c.xml"/>
```

Now all definitions of `b.xml` and `c.xml` will be available in `a.xml`

and you can just define them combined in any of xml's

```
<context:property-placeholder
location="classpath:a.properties,
          classpath:b.properties,
          classpath:c.properties"
ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

or if you are not using `context` namespace

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:a.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:b.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:c.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the scenario correctly, you have 3 configs for each environment? Maybe regional, and you switch between the different xml files.

What you should do instead is have just one xml file, that resolves to properties in a properties file.

You have one properties file per environment in your resources folder.

At startup you can then pass a jvm argument to set the "region" or way you identify the environment which will then "fill" your xml where there are placeholders to the values in the properties files.

This [site](http://www.baeldung.com/project-configuration-with-spring) should help you get started.